# Angular, ngrx - problem with infinitive loop in selector

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

There is possible to dispatch action in selector in one store?

```
    this.store$.pipe(select(selectPersonByName, {personSelectorProps: this.id[]0}))
            .subscribe(history => {
                this.store$.dispatch(selectAssignWorkHistory({historyArray:  history}));
            });
    }
```

When I run that code, I have infinitive loop. Dispatch action refresh the store, and re-run selector and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this action meant to be fired once upon subscribing to the store selector, you may chain the above statement the RxJS `take()` [operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html). This operator will ensure that only the specified count values supplied to be `take()` operator will be emitted by the source observable.

```
this.store$
  .pipe(
    select(selectPersonByName, {personSelectorProps: this.id[0]}),
    take(1),
  ).subscribe(history => {
    this.store$.dispatch(selectAssignWorkHistory({historyArray:  history}));
  });
```

Comment: Thank You! I must refresh my knowledge about rxjs.